# Manage subscription on Android app

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

I need to add a subscription support to my application, so that the user can buy a subscription for a year of service.
I just have created the subscription on Google Developer Console.
My problem is: I don't have any idea how I can check the user subscription.
I'm working to do this:

1. When my app is started by the user, if there is network, the app contacts the Play Store and checks if the user has bought the subscription and the payment date. These data are always saved on locale file, so if there is no network the app will use the local data for checking;
2. If the user has bought the subscription I check if it's been over a year. In fact I have read on internet that Play Store provides only the payment date and not the finish subscription date;
3. If the checking is true the app will work in Premium mode and not in Standard mode;

Now the problems:

1. How do I check the purchase? Can I use hasPurchase() method like in normal in-app?
2. If I need to use hasPurchase() on point 1) does this method return False if the user don't renew the subscription after a year?
3. How can I know the purchase date?

I copy a piece of code, this is a valid code to check normal in-app and I'd like to edit it to use it in subscription checking:

```
    private void checkForPremium() {
    final IabHelper buyHelper = new IabHelper(this, "MYKEY");

    // initialize the InApp Billing system
    buyHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                buyHelper.dispose();

                Log.e("MYAPP", "Error: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Get a list of all products the user owns
            buyHelper.queryInventoryAsync(new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
                    if (result.isFailure()) {
                        buyHelper.dispose();

                        Log.e("MYAPP", "Error: " + result);
                    } else {
                        boolean isPremium = inv.hasPurchase("MYSKU");
                        inv.getSkuDetails().

                        buyHelper.dispose();

                        // Forward to the currect activity depending on premium / demo mode
                        if (isPremium) {
                            if(menu != null){
                                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_premium);
                                item.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            Log.w("MYAPP", "PREMIUM");
                        } else {
                            if(menu != null){
                                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_premium);
                                item.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            Log.w("MYAPP", "NO PREMIUM");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Subscription. but AFAIK Play store maintains purchase information locally. You should not store it locally (As you will have a overhead of encryption those subscription information). Play store will return you purchase information even if data connection is off.

Comment: @KalpeshPatel this sound good. but I don't know how retrive the information :)

Comment: As I have not worked on subscription, I don't know how to retrieve purchase information. But I think it should be same as normal in-app billing. Check this [link.](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching) this very clearly states that purchase information are cached locally.
Also you can read Subscription paragraph of this [link.](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttypes) It clearly says that there is no difference in purchase API of subscription product and in-app products. that means you can use getPurchases request for purchase info.